# StringBuilder returing Web script

Tags: c#, asp.net

Task : With the page_type and currentpage param I made this code that returns the web script of the web page with active class on the current page through aspx behind code.

Is there a better and a shorter way of code that works just like the code below? (The difference is the else if(page_type == sales) script.append part)

```
protected string MakeBottomMenu(string page_type)
    {
        StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
        string currentPage = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

        if (page_type == "office")
        {
            if(currentPage.Equals("commute_gps.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"commute_gps.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"home\"><span class=\"blind\">홈</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"commute_gps.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"home\"><span class=\"blind\">홈</span></a></li>");

            if (currentPage.Equals("visit_location.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"visit_location.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"locate_office\"><span class=\"blind\">방문업체</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"visit_location.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"locate_office\"><span class=\"blind\">방문업체</span></a></li>");

            if(currentPage.Equals("approval_request.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"approval_request.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"request\"><span class=\"blind\">근무기록</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"approval_request.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"request\"><span class=\"blind\">근무기록</span></a></li>");

            if (currentPage.Equals("address_book.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"address_book.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"address\"><span class=\"blind\">주소록</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"address_book.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"address\"><span class=\"blind\">주소록</span></a></li>");
        }

        else if (page_type == "onsite")
        {
            if (currentPage.Equals("commute_gps.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"commute_gps.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"home\"><span class=\"blind\">홈</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"commute_gps.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"home\"><span class=\"blind\">홈</span></a></li>");

            if (currentPage.Equals("visit_location.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"visit_location.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"locate_office\"><span class=\"blind\">방문업체</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"visit_location.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"locate_office\"><span class=\"blind\">방문업체</span></a></li>");

            if (currentPage.Equals("approval_request.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"approval_request.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"request\"><span class=\"blind\">근무기록</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"approval_request.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"request\"><span class=\"blind\">근무기록</span></a></li>");

            if (currentPage.Equals("address_book.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"address_book.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"address\"><span class=\"blind\">주소록</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"address_book.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"address\"><span class=\"blind\">주소록</span></a></li>");
        }

        else if (page_type == "sales")
        {
            if (currentPage.Equals("sales_calendar.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"sales_calendar.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"home\"><span class=\"blind\">홈</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"sales_calendar.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"home\"><span class=\"blind\">홈</span></a></li>");

            if (currentPage.Equals("visit_location.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"visit_location.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"locate_office\" ><span class=\"blind\" > 방문업체</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"visit_location.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"locate_office\" ><span class=\"blind\" > 방문업체</span></a></li>");

            if (currentPage.Equals("approval_request.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"approval_request.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"request\" ><span class=\"blind\" > 근무기록</span></a></li>");
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"approval_request.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"request\" ><span class=\"blind\" > 근무기록</span></a></li>");

            if (currentPage.Equals("address_book.aspx"))
                script.Append($"<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"address_book.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"address\" ><span class=\"blind\" > 주소록</span></a></li>");                
            else
                script.Append($"<li><a href=\"address_book.aspx?page_type={page_type}\" class=\"address\" ><span class=\"blind\" > 주소록</span></a></li>");
        }

        return script.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Answer (score 2):

Some quick remarks:

- Don't use underscores in variable names (`page_type`).
- Why do you call this a "script"? You're returning a list of `LI`s, i.e. list items.
- On a related note: why a `StringBuilder`? This is a list of strings that at the end gets returned as a single string. So why then not work with a `List<string>` and use `string.Join()` at the end?
- If you find yourself copy-pasting things over and over again and changing only parts of what you copy-pasted, you should stop copy-pasting and instead write a method that takes the necessary arguments and returns the required string. All of your list items are the same, except for the LI's class, the link's class, part of the link's URL and the text that is displayed. Imagine you need to change something in that HTML: if this was the return of a method, you'd only need to change it in one place, not dozens.
- The logic inside `page_type == "office"` and `page_type == "onsite"` seems to be identical. Why then have separate blocks? Again: do not copy-paste code.